# How to access a div target to toggle styling for a list group item in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am attempting to build out a set of items you can click on and off using `react-bootstrap` and am having trouble accessing the target value of a `ListGroup.Item` in my function. Basically I want to:

1. click the specific item
2. upon clicking turn that item green
3. if any other items are green the color should be removed, so that only the item that is recently clicked is green

I am trying to do this with a `handleCheck` function that uses the target value to toggle a json property but can't get it to work. `event.target.value` is showing `undefined` and I am unsure how to make this work.

Here is a working example of the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/targetvalue-zqrkz?file=/src/App.js:1070-1071

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `value` directly in `accordion` component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Accordion,
  Card,
  ListGroup,
  DropdownButton,
  Dropdown,
  Image
} from "react-bootstrap";
import { FaChevronCircleDown, FaChevronCircleUp } from "react-icons/fa";
import classes from "./accordian.module.css";

const MainMenu = (props) => {
  const [opened, setOpened] = useState(true);

  const testingSmthFin = (x) => {
    props.testingSmthSec(x);
  };

  const handleTimer = (x) => {
    props.testingTimer(x);
  };

  let dropDown = null;
  if (props.regions) {
    dropDown = (
      <div>
        {props.regions.map((region, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              <ListGroup.Item
                value={region.region}
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: region.isChecked ? "#90EE90" : "White"
                }}
                onClick={(e) => props.handleCheck(region.region, i)} //<------------------
              >
                {region.region}
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Accordion
      defaultActiveKey={props.showAccordian}
      className={classes.mainMenu}
    >
      <Card style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: "#ffffff78" }}>
        <Accordion.Toggle
          as={Card.Header}
          eventKey="0"
          style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: "#3f4042ba" }}
          onClick={() => setOpened(!opened)}
        >
          <text style={{ color: "beige", fontWeight: "bolder" }}> </text>
          <text style={{ color: "beige" }}>: MY ACCORDIAN </text>
          {opened ? (
            <FaChevronCircleUp color="white" />
          ) : (
            <FaChevronCircleDown color="white" />
          )}
        </Accordion.Toggle>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
          <Card.Body
            style={{
              padding: 10,
              backgroundColor: "white",
              borderRadius: "3%"
            }}
          >
            <ListGroup>
              <ListGroup.Item></ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
          <Card.Body
            style={{
              padding: 10,
              backgroundColor: "white",
              marginTop: 10,
              borderRadius: "3%"
            }}
          >
            <Card.Title style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
              Check region
            </Card.Title>
            <ListGroup>
              {/* <ListGroup.Item 
                onClick={props.sliceGeo} 
                style={{ backgroundColor: props.checked ? '#90EE90' : 'White' }} 
              >Citywide
              {
                props.checked ?
                <Image
                  style={{marginLeft: '50%'}} 
                  src={checked} 
                  width="20"
                  height="20"
                /> : <div></div>
              }      
              </ListGroup.Item> */}
              {dropDown}
              {/* <ListGroup.Item >Midtown</ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>Queens</ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>Brooklyn</ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>Bronx</ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>Staten Island</ListGroup.Item> */}
            </ListGroup>
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
    </Accordion>
  );
};

export default MainMenu;
```

```
handleCheck = (value, key) => {                      // <---------------------
    //copy all items
    let regions = [...this.state.regions];
    //extract the itemn we care about
    let item = { ...regions[key] };

    //for the extacted item, check it
    //item.isChecked = !item.isChecked;

    //MY ATTEMPT BELOW
    console.log(value);                         // <---------------------------
    // regions.map((item) => {
    //   if (item.region === event.target.value) {
    //     item.isChecked = true;
    //   } else {
    //     item.isChecked = false;
    //   }
    // });

    //reassign value
    regions[key] = item;

    this.setState({ regions });
    console.log(regions);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Final Output:

[image]

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Accordian from "./Accordian";

const data = [
  { region: "Citywide", isChecked: false },
  { region: "Midtown", isChecked: false },
  { region: "Queens", isChecked: false },
  { region: "Brooklyn", isChecked: false },
  { region: "Bronx", isChecked: false },
  { region: "Staten Island", isChecked: false }
];
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      regions: data
    };
  }

  handleCheck = (event, key) => {
    // reset all values of regions
    let regions = [...data];
    let item = { ...regions[key], isChecked: true };
    // ☝ set the isChecked value of selected item and we are done.
    console.log("regions[key]", regions[key]);
    regions[key] = item;
    this.setState({ regions }, () => console.log("key:", regions));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Accordian
          regions={this.state.regions}
          handleCheck={this.handleCheck}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Working App: [Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/targetvalue-forked-8d04l?file=/src/App.js:0-965)